# No output from Node app

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to run a simple node application using nide modules and testing it using the Advance Rest Client.

The console is not showing any error.
But I am not getting anything in the output.
[image: This is the main file]

[image: This is the router file]

While running this on ARC, I am getting : Cannot /GET data

Text version of the code:
MainFile:

```
var express = require('express');
//var morgan = require('morgan');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');

var hostname = 'localhost';
var port = '3000';

var app = express();
//app.use(morgan('dev'));

var dishRouter = express.Router();
dishRouter.use(bodyparser.json());

var allDishes = require('./dishRouter');

//For all dishes
dishRouter.route('/dishes')
.get(allDishes.dishesGet)
.delete(allDishes.dishesDelete)
.post(allDishes.dishesPost)
;

//For specific dishesDelete
dishRouter.route('/dishes/:dishid')
.get(allDishes.dishSpecificGet)
.delete(allDishes.dishSpecificDelete)
.put(allDishes.dishSpecificPut)
;

app.listen(port,hostname,function(){
    console.log('server runing properly');
});
```

dishRouter file:

```
console.log('in dishrouter file');


module.exports.dishesGet = function(req,res,next){
    console.log('inside GET');
    res.end('Will be displaying all the dishes');
};

module.exports.dishesDelete = function(req,res,next){
    res.end('Will delete all the dishes');
};

module.exports.dishesPost = function(req,res,next){
    res.end('will add the new dishes');
};

module.exports.dishSpecificGet = function(req,res,next){
    res.end('displaying the specific dish :'+req.params.dishid);
};

module.exports.dishSpecificDelete = function(req,res,next){
    res.end('Will delete the specific dish with id : '+req.params.dishid);
};

module.exports.dishSpecificPut = function(req,res,next){
    res.write('will update the specific dish :'+req.params.dishid);
    res.end('Updating the dish with values as name : '+req.body.name);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

According to body-parser [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)

Looks like your router is a bit broken here:

```
dishRouter.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Try switching this to:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

And I can recommend creating router in the file, where you write handlers and just export router.

**UPDATE:**
Here is what you forgot:

```
app.use(dishRouter)
```

When calling `express.Router()` you're just creating an instance of the router, but you have to connect it to the express application instance.

Comment: Using app.use(bodyParser.json()) is also not helping. Still getting the same output

Comment: would be nice if you provide text version of your code =)

Comment: what can I suggest is: comment out "morgan" and check if you still have no output

Comment: Tried commenting it.
But still no output

Comment: Oh great great.
Thanks